# Recive Value from RecyclerViewAdapter Class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I got an RecyclerView in my Main Activity, where the Items got a Like Button. In my RecyclerViewAdapter Class I got the OnClickListener which receives the ID of the Item.

What I want to do is:
Pass the ID of the Item to the MainActivity. I tried it with Intents in the OnClickMethod of the RecycerViewAdapter Class, but if I would use it like this I would need something like a Listener for the Intent in the MainActivity. The other Idea was to set an OnClickListener for the Button in the MainActivity. But I cant set an OnClickListener for an Item of the RecyclerView in the Main Acitivity.

Does someone know how I can solve my Problem?

Comment: you need an interface between adapter and activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two straightforward ways I can think of:

1. Use a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)
2. Define an interface and pass the instance to the Adapter. Then call the appropriate method when the click is performed.

BTW, why do you want to pass the value back to the Activity? Can't you perform the work withing the adapter?

Comment: I want to pass the ID of the Item to the MainAcitivity so I can put the userID and the Item ID in my MySQL Database. It's a Like, Comment, and Dislike Function.

Comment: Why not just define a method that performs it and call it from the adapter (just to keep the code clean)?

Comment: You mean to get put the userID in the Recycler class? Im sorry for being so complicated but in really new in this RecylcerView Stuff...

Comment: Since you have all the data when you build the row, you can pass it to a method to perform the action. And don't worry about the being complicated. We were all new once. :)

Comment: Ok if I understood it right you mean i can make a new Class/Method where everything comes together and performe the action?

Comment: Just create a method outside of the adapter and call it from the "OnClick" method within the the adapter.